Why are times different on different Arduino Pro Minis?
I am working on a project using a 5v Arduino Pro Mini. To save power I have it power down and wake up every about 15 minutes to check on the battery strength and then power down again. This cycle runs 8 times when I have it wake up and then run through my main code, checking sensors and then handing those reading off to an ESP8266-1 to send the information to Adafruit. I have built three units using the same components/configuration and the exact same code. On one of the Arduino Pro Minis the elapse time is about 1hr 55min. on another it is about 1hr. 56min. 30seconds while the third is about 1hr. 59min. 50seconds. Why is there a difference between the three. I can understand being a few seconds different based on how fast the ESP8266-1 connects to the internet and transmits the data but a difference of 4minutes I don't understand. Can someone explain why this happens? Or should I be posting this somewhere else. Thanks.

probably dependent on the code

What do you use to wake up? Could you reduce your sketch to a minimum, reproducible, and complete example? Please [edit] your question to add new information.

WiFi scan will take from 6s to sometime more than 10s... Connecting to a server could also varies depend on network traffic and server readiness... If you program your Arduino Pro Mini to only wake up once at 2 hour, will you still see the difference of 4 mins? Also, are you using the external crystal during power down mode, or the internal oscillator (8MHz or 128KHz) on your Pro Mini?

The Arduino Mini Pro uses the ATMEGA328 processor. That processor has six sleep modes (described in this data sheet).
Beyond that, there are techniques one can explore to extend power savings down to the mA range and less. One such possible technique could use the WDT which runs on an internal oscillator to wake up the processor.
From the data sheet:

Atmel ® ATmega328P has an enhanced watchdog timer (WDT). The WDT is a timer counting cycles of a separate on-chip
128kHz oscillator

The slower oscillator will likely save on power requirements. However, it is unlikely such an oscillator will be as accurate as the higher frequency crystal based oscillator used by the ATMEGA328 during normal operation.
If the length of sleep needs to be more accurate, consider adjusting the sleep time to compensate for processor to processor discrepancies. Note, the internal ATMEAG328 128kHz oscillator may not be as stable across temperature changes as a crystal based oscillator.

This 128 kHz oscillator is indeed notoriously inaccurate and unstable... but it draws very little power.
